# Unable to open a file using Open in... since Xcode 9.3

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging

Prior to Xcode 9.3 I had no issues importing a file, now when attempting to open a file using open in the app crashes with

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

It doesn't even reach my

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

    let urlName = url.lastPathComponent
    print("Gotten a file \(urlName)")
}
```

So before my app even gets the file it crashes which I dont understand

In the AppDelegate

I also created a new empty project and getting the same issue

These are the necessary document settings

[image]

The crash location

[image]

Comment: Where is your app crashing?

Comment: You need to enable exception breakpoints so you can see where the app really crashes.

Comment: Still getting results as before - the import of the file should trigger that method in the app delegate but its bugging out before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just by luck I came across this method

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

      // read in your file 

}
```

So replaced the method above with this and it worked.

Comment: Thanks! I was struggling with this but your answer pointed me in the right direction.
Looks like `application(_:open:sourceApplication:annotation:)` was deprecated in iOS 9 but Xcode was not giving warnings. Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623073-application